# Dropdown Menu Not Displaying CSS/Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 3rd level menu working. But only displays one of the dropdowns, the other appears hidden.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Can't see anything blocking in CSS

**Here is the Plunker** https://plnkr.co/edit/XUS2SdMDw4HkPpB80tvm?p=preview

[image]

It should show

**Presentation Videos**

**Designer Videos**

but only shows

**Presentation Videos**

```
<div id="cssmenu"><div id="menu-button">Menu</div>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span><a href="extractor-fans">Extractor Fans</a>
            <ul style="">
                <li><a class="arrow" href="/bathroom-extractor-fans">Bathroom Shower</a>
                    <div class="has-sub"><span class="submenu-button"></span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="bathroom-vids">Designer Videos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="bathroom-vids2">Presentation Videos</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ceiling-bathroom"> Bathroom Cabinets</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your plunkr doesn’t show any dropdown - jquery is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `height:0` from below class

```
 #cssmenu ul ul li
{
height: 0;

-webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
   -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease;
        transition: all .25s ease;
}
```